# pandas.DataFrame.to_csv adds data on the same line as previous data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly, spotipy

I am trying to use the Spotipy package to export audio features for various songs, and plotting them using Plotly.

I used a tkinter gui so I can enter the song name there and the command sends it to the CSV.
All of that seems to be working properly, however when the data exports to the CSV it adds it on the same line as the previous line, instead of a new line

The problem did not exist the entire time, but I can't recall a specific thing that may have prompted it starting. I'm really new to Python/programming so I apologize for my code.

Here's the function in which the writing to the CSV occurs:

```
def find_song(trackid):
        #Returns results as a list of dictionaries
    results = sp.audio_features(tracks=[trackid])
    #change list of dictionaries into a dataframe
    audio_features = pd.DataFrame(results)
    #Acquiring and labeling song name, artist name, today's date
    song = sp.track(trackid)['name']
    artist = sp.track(trackid)['artists']
    artist_info = pd.DataFrame(artist)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    artistname = artist_info.name[0]
    date = '%d/%d/%d' % (now.month, now.day, now.year)
    audio_features['Artist'] = artistname
    audio_features['Song Name'] = song
    audio_features['Date'] = date
    #New dataframe of only relevant information
    audio_features = audio_features[['Date','Artist', 'Song Name', 'acousticness', 'analysis_url', 'danceability', 'duration_ms', 'energy', 'id', 'instrumentalness', 'key', 'liveness', 'loudness', 'mode', 'speechiness', 'tempo', 'time_signature', 'track_href', 'type', 'uri', 'valence']]
    plot_me()
    audio_features.to_csv("/Users/username/Documents/CSV's_Landing/spotify_data.csv", mode='a', header=False)
```

I intend for the audio feature data for each new song to show up on a new line in the csv like so:

```
'Date','Artist','SongName','acousticness','analysis_url','danceability','duration_ms'
'0','8/8/2019','Post Animal', 'When I Get Home', '0.0665', 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/5azJUob8ahbXB3M9YFwTpd', '0.245','323200'
'0','8/8/2019','BROCKHAMPTON', 'I BEEN BORN AGAIN', '0.324', 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/5fiR9Dy9hNXEPZOLo1kyNb', '0.73', '219720'
```

Instead, it looks like this:

```
'Date','Artist','SongName','acousticness','analysis_url','danceability','duration_ms'
'0','8/8/2019','Post Animal', 'When I Get Home', '0.0665', 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/5azJUob8ahbXB3M9YFwTpd', '0.245','323200','8/8/2019','BROCKHAMPTON', 'I BEEN BORN AGAIN', '0.324', 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/5fiR9Dy9hNXEPZOLo1kyNb', '0.73', '219720'
```

So basically, tacking what's supposed to be the new line onto the previous line. It doesn't add another "Index" number, either. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this happening for every single line in your data, or only for some?

Comment: Also, it seems you have pd referring to Pandas, so then what does op.to_csv refer to?  Are you sure you're using Pandas.to_csv?

Comment: @JulianDrago My bad! I had originally had audio_features as "op" just because I was lazy :-] Edited! Also, it happens once but because of it, on the next run pandas gives me an error when it tries to read the csv

Comment: @JulianDrago ```pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 24 fields in line 4, saw 45```